# ARM template fails when creating event hub in multiple regions with multiple auth rules

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have an ARM template that creates Event Hub namespaces in two regions (eastus and westus2) with a event hub and multiple auth rules (on the even hub). This was working until ~16-Nov-2020 12:00PM.
Arm template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {    
    "location-region1": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "eastus",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of an azure region"
      }
    },
    "location-region2": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "westus2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of an Azure region"
      }
    },   
    "appName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "jklm",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Short name of the app or service"
      }
    },
    "uniqueSuffix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "tst",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Unique Suffix to use for the azure resources of the app or service"
      }
    },
    "environment": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "int",
      "allowedValues": [
        "poc",
        "dev",
        "int",
        "uat",
        "prod"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the environment"
      }
    },   
    "progressRecordsEventHubName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "progressrecords"
    }
  },
  "variables": {    
    "eventHubNMApiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
    "eventHubApiVersion": "2017-04-01",    
    "parentResourceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]",
    "regionCount": 2,  
    "location": [
      "[parameters('location-region1')]",
      "[parameters('location-region2')]"
    ],
   
    "appName": "[concat(parameters('appName'),'-',parameters('uniqueSuffix'),'-')]",
   
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "regionSuffix",
        "count": "[variables('regionCount')]",
        "input": "[concat('r',copyIndex('regionSuffix',1))]"
      },
      {
        "name": "eventHubName",
        "count": "[variables('regionCount')]",
        "input": "[concat(variables('appName'),'ehub-',variables('regionSuffix')[copyIndex('eventHubName')],'-',parameters('environment'))]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "resources": [
   
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('eventHubNMApiVersion')]",
      "name": "[variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex()]]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "resourceLoop",
        "count": "[variables('regionCount')]"
      },
      "location": "[variables('location')[copyIndex()]]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "capacity": 1
      },
      "properties": {
        "zoneRedundant": false,
        "isAutoInflateEnabled": true,
        "maximumThroughputUnits": 1,
        "kafkaEnabled": true
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs",
          "apiVersion": "[variables('eventHubApiVersion')]",
          "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex()], '/',parameters('progressRecordsEventHubName'))]",
          "location": "[variables('location')[copyIndex()]]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex()])]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "messageRetentionInDays": 3,
            "partitionCount": 1,
            "status": "Active"
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules",
              "apiVersion": "[variables('eventHubApiVersion')]",
              "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex('resourceLoop')], '/',parameters('progressRecordsEventHubName'),'/Listen')]",
              "location": "[variables('location')[copyIndex()]]",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs', variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex()],parameters('progressRecordsEventHubName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "rights": [
                  "Listen"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules",
              "apiVersion": "[variables('eventHubApiVersion')]",
              "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex('resourceLoop')], '/',parameters('progressRecordsEventHubName'),'/Send')]",
              "location": "[variables('location')[copyIndex()]]",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs', variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex()], parameters('progressRecordsEventHubName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "rights": [
                  "Send"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }      
  ],
  "functions": [    
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Now this template fails when I run `Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`  (add `-Debug` to see real error)
Error:

```
Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Encountered internal server error. Diagnostic information: timestamp '20201119T072227Z' ......
```

After some troubleshooting I identified that removing the second auth rule in the template fixes the issue.
**I actually need more than 1 auth rule. What could be causing the above template to fail? I can't seem to find anything wrong with it.**
Below you can find successful template - With 1 auth rule on the Event Hub

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {    
    "location-region1": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "eastus"
    },
    "location-region2": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "westus2"
    },   
    "appName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "jklm",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Short name of the app or service"
      }
    },
    "uniqueSuffix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "tst",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Unique Suffix to use for the azure resources of the app or service"
      }
    },
    "environment": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "int",
      "allowedValues": [
        "poc",
        "dev",
        "int",
        "uat",
        "prod"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the environment"
      }
    },   
    "progressRecordsEventHubName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "progressrecords"
    }
  },
  "variables": {    
    "eventHubNMApiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
    "eventHubApiVersion": "2017-04-01",    
    "parentResourceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]",
    "regionCount": 2,  
    "location": [
      "[parameters('location-region1')]",
      "[parameters('location-region2')]"
    ],   
    "appName": "[concat(parameters('appName'),'-',parameters('uniqueSuffix'),'-')]",   
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "regionSuffix",
        "count": "[variables('regionCount')]",
        "input": "[concat('r',copyIndex('regionSuffix',1))]"
      },
      {
        "name": "eventHubName",
        "count": "[variables('regionCount')]",
        "input": "[concat(variables('appName'),'ehub-',variables('regionSuffix')[copyIndex('eventHubName')],'-',parameters('environment'))]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "resources": [
   
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('eventHubNMApiVersion')]",
      "name": "[variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex()]]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "resourceLoop",
        "count": "[variables('regionCount')]"
      },
      "location": "[variables('location')[copyIndex()]]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "capacity": 1
      },
      "properties": {
        "zoneRedundant": false,
        "isAutoInflateEnabled": true,
        "maximumThroughputUnits": 1,
        "kafkaEnabled": true
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs",
          "apiVersion": "[variables('eventHubApiVersion')]",
          "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex()], '/',parameters('progressRecordsEventHubName'))]",
          "location": "[variables('location')[copyIndex()]]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex()])]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "messageRetentionInDays": 3,
            "partitionCount": 1,
            "status": "Active"
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules",
              "apiVersion": "[variables('eventHubApiVersion')]",
              "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex('resourceLoop')], '/',parameters('progressRecordsEventHubName'),'/Listen')]",
              "location": "[variables('location')[copyIndex()]]",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs', variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex()],parameters('progressRecordsEventHubName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "rights": [
                  "Listen"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }      
  ],
  "functions": [    
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked with Azure support on this. There was an issue on the Azure side. It auto resolved today (11/19/2020). Template no longer fails with multiple auth rules.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be useful: https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/error-creating-service-bus-authorization-rules-using-arm/.

I think the template is not expecting the same resource twice, because these `Listen, Send` authorization rules can be combined like below:

```
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules",
              "apiVersion": "[variables('eventHubApiVersion')]",
              "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex('resourceLoop')], '/',parameters('progressRecordsEventHubName'),'/Listen')]",
              "location": "[variables('location')[copyIndex()]]",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs', variables('eventHubName')[copyIndex()],parameters('progressRecordsEventHubName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "rights": [
                  "Listen",
                  "Send"
                ]
              }
            },
```